# Openstack image create stuck in queued state

Tags: linux, server, cloud, virtual-machine, openstack

I've installed openstack on my workstation and i've been trying to create ubuntu focal image. I've download the cloud image and created using the following config [image] , but i couldnt pass the queue state when creating. I've also tried it using the cli and the cli returns

```
HTTP 502 Bad Gateway: Bad Gateway: The proxy server received an invalid: response from an upstream server.: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.100.15 Port 80
```

Comment: Hello Mike, I have the same problem. Did u solve it?

Comment: Hey @khalid3e not yet